# How to set a variable in a controller as the contents of a file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following file:

```
/app/views/admin/newsletters/1_announcement_html.html.erb
```

In the admin controller, I want to set the contents of this file as a variable to allow me to send the var to the user mailer. How can I do this? I have:

```
  def newsletter_deliver
    from = params[:from]
    to = params[:to]
    bcc = params[:bcc]
    subject = params[:subject]

    text = render :file => "admin/newsletters/1_announcement_text.html.erb"
    html = render :file => "admin/newsletters/1_announcement_html.html.erb"

    UserMailer.newsletter(from,to,bcc,subject,html,text).deliver

    render :text => 'Sent'
  end
```

This errors with a DoubleRenderError. Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [render_to_string](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-render_to_string) instead of `render` when assigning to a variable.